# Database design data model mapping (direct vs roll-down vs roll up)

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I'm designing a small database (~30 tables) for my project. I am currently wondering which approach I should take.

Say (for the sake of argument), we have a snippet of the Domain Model with the following structure.

1. Employees are paid once per month
2. There are two types of employees:

   -Permanent employee (paid same amount monthly + bonus)

   -Paid per hour employee (PPH)

The relation in Domain Model is as follows:
`Abstract Employee`
`Permanent Employee : Employee`
`PPH_Employee : Employee`

Lets assume the employee table looks like this:
`Employee (employee_id (PK), last_name, first_name, salary)`

We can apply 3 different data mappings here:

Direct:

`Employee (employee_id (PK), last_name, first_name, salary)`

`Permanent_Employee (employee_id (FK), bonus)`

`PPH_Employee (employee_id (FK), no_of_hours, hourly_wage)`

Roll Down:

`Permanent_Employee (employee_id (PK), last_name, first_name, salary, bonus)`

`PPH_Employee (employee_id (PK), last_name, first_name, salary, no_of_hours, hourly_wage)`

Roll Up:

`Employee (employee_id (PK), last_name, first_name, salary, bonus, no_of_hours, hourly_wage, type_of_employee)`

Is there any mapping I would favor over the others (any solid / objective reasons in favoring one over the other)? And if so, could someone shed some light on why certain choice is favorable?

Comment: Do permanent employees every become pph employees, or vice-versa? Do you need to know when the person had, or will have, a pay rise? Can a pay rise occur during a pay period?

Comment: In this example: 1. They cannot become one another (Perm<-->PPH) in a sense that if such transfer occurs it will be treated as separate account 2. For the moment such data does not need to be tracked. 3. Payment increase is treated on a monthly basis - so if pay is increased it will affect all hours in the given month. (This are the made up rules - as the data here was given as an example, if I understand correctly the meaning behind the question, if e.g. the transfer could occur, using TYPE flag would be preferable option?)

Comment: Usually the "direct" style is used. Search re subtyping in database designs.